# CLion 2017.3 unable to autocomplete through unique_ptr using clang 5 (works with 4.0.1)

Tags: c++, clang, clion, clang++

**edit: scroll to bold section below for current status.**

CLion seems to be unable to autocomplete members of a type pointed to by a unique_ptr in clang 5.   I either get "no suggestions" or I get suggestions for member functions on the `unique_ptr` itself:

[image]

[image]

However, with 4.0.1, everything works fine:

[image]

I also noticed that if I ask CLion to jump to the definition of the `->` on `c->`, in 4.0.1 it finds it:

```
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY pointer operator->() const _NOEXCEPT {return __ptr_.first();}
```

But in 5.0.0, the same command says:  `Cannot find declaration to go to`, so that seems to be closer to the root of the problem.

`shared_ptr-><AUTOCOMPLETE>` works fine in both versions.

**Simplifying the code in `<memory>` for `unique_ptr::operator->`'s return type to `element_type *` fixes the problem, but changing core include files isn't something I love doing.**  Confusingly, that part of the code in 5.0 is the same as it is in 4.0.1 where it works fine.

```
  _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
  element_type * operator->() const _NOEXCEPT {
      return __ptr_.first();
  }  _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY

    // original code that doesn't play nice with CLion
//    pointer operator->() const _NOEXCEPT {
//        return __ptr_.first();
//    }
```

I'm interested in any workarounds or even just an explanation as to what is going on to cause this.

I'm on a Mac pre-built binaries from the llvm download site.  I'm wondering if it's an issue with the Apple clang numbering scheme vs the *real* clang version numbers.  Maybe the clang analyzer thinks I'm on some ancient version of (apple) clang instead of modern "real" clang.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to change the return type of `unique_ptr::operator->` in the `memory` header.

```
  _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
  element_type * operator->() const _NOEXCEPT {
      return __ptr_.first();
  }  _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY

    // original code that doesn't play nice with CLion
//    pointer operator->() const _NOEXCEPT {
//        return __ptr_.first();
//    }
```

Makes things work and more closely mirrors how things are done in `shared_ptr`, which works out of the box.

Comment: I have reason to question if this change is not fully compliant with the spec, but it hasn't bitten me yet...

Answer (score 0):

I want to follow up here that the above (accepted) solution works with the libstdc++ implementation of `unique_ptr` as well, at least the one that came with GCC 8.1 that I am using.

Another solution, for reasons I detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61000033/netbeans-8-2-code-assistance-issue-with-unique-ptr-not-shared-ptr/61002871#61002871), is that you can add a `using` directive at the beginning of the structure like `using pointer = C*`. This fools Netbeans into auto-completing properly without warnings. This solution may be specific to libstdc++, but based on your answer, it looks like libc++ internally uses the same typename for the pointer.